# LINQ Distinct rows with multiple joins

Tags: mysql, linq, join, distinct

i am having trouble trying to get all distinct rows, as information from multiple tables with joins using linq, and returning only single rows of data for each product. The joins return multiple rows for each product

First Version

```
    select DISTINCT * from z_product as zp
inner join orders_products op on zp.ProductId = op.products_id
inner join products p on op.products_id = p.products_id
inner join orders o on o.orders_id = op.orders_id
inner join product_design d on d.products_id = p.products_id
where tray = 35 
group by zp.Id
```

kind of what i want, 
results 2 products with all information in Mysql Workbench

Second Version

Attempt at grabbing information without grouping on the outer, But i will need to list all the columns i need. Something i dont want to do yet.

Do i have to list every column? 
How can i do this in LINQ?

```
    select  ass.* from z_product as zass LEFT JOIN ( SELECT zp.* from z_product as zp
    left join orders_products op on zp.ProductId = op.products_id
    left join products p on op.products_id = p.products_id
    left join orders o on o.orders_id = op.orders_id
    left join product_design d on d.products_id = p.products_id
    left join orders_products_attributes a on a.orders_products_id  =  op.orders_id
    group by zp.Id) ass
    ON ass.Id = zass.Id
    where zass.Tray=35
```

kind of what i want, 
results 2 products with all information in Mysql Workbench

[what i do want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJ9Qo.png)

```
So i want to get something like this;
 [What i want in LINQ][1]

Attempt version 1 in LINQ

                var orderProducts = (from zp in SqlContext.z_product
                    join op in SqlContext.orders_products on zp.ProductId equals op.products_id
                    join p in SqlContext.products on op.products_id equals p.products_id
                    join o in SqlContext.orders on op.orders_id equals o.orders_id
                    join d in SqlContext.product_design on p.products_id equals d.products_id
                    join a in SqlContext.orders_products_attributes on op.orders_id equals
                    a.orders_products_id
                    where zp.Tray == SelectedTray.Id
                    group new Product
                    {
                        OrdersProduct = op,
                        Product = p,
                        Order = o,
                        AreaProduct = zp,
                        ProductDesign = d,
                        OrdersProductsAttributes = a,
                    } by zp.Id
                    into product
                    select product);
```

[what i dont want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8lKEy.png)

Attempt using comprehensive? linq Will produce groups of products. Each group will have a list of objects. I want just 2 products.

2 groups, each group is a list of its items. I just want to have 2 products.

Comment: If you have a working SQL query that produces the desired result, then post only that query (and make sure to include column aliases, including the *). Also specify your ORM (LinqToSQL, EF (version), EF Core etc.), model classes and relationships.

Comment: They both work fine, but im not sure totally of their integrity. I want to use EF6 with an existing DB that has no relationships.

What do you mean by "include column aliases, including the *). " Everything is there.

Comment: @IvanStoev Why -1  my question? the ORM shouldnt even matter using c# expression here. The aliases are all their etc. Your input and mark down are invalid?

Comment: I can't say why, because -1 is not by me:)

Comment: @IvanStoev Apologies

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

So i found it, using .First() within a grouping.

```
            var orderProducts = (from zp in SqlContext.product
                             join op in SqlContext.orders_products on zp.ProductId equals op.orders_products_id
                             join p in SqlContext.products on op.products_id equals p.products_id
                             join o in SqlContext.orders on op.orders_id equals o.orders_id
                             join d in SqlContext.product_design on p.products_id equals d.products_id
                             join a in SqlContext.orders_products_attributes on op.orders_id equals
                             a.orders_products_id
                             where zp.Tray == tray
                             group new Product
                             {
                                 SiblingCount = (from oop in SqlContext.orders_products
                                                 where oop.orders_id == o.orders_id
                                                 select oop
                                         ).Count(),
                                 OrdersProduct = op,
                                 Product = p,
                                 Order = o,
                                 AreaProduct = zp,
                                 ProductDesign = d,
                                 OrdersProductsAttributes = a,
                             } by zp.Id
                             into product
                             select product.First());
```

Gets the first element from each group.